# Replace char if line contain a specific word. Regex "Find and Replace"

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I want to replace only the char `;` if line contain the word `"eeeeeeeeee"` with this `);`
using Regular Expression with "Find and Replace" tool in visual studio

```
text = rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["TextForignHead"] as TextObject;
Adapters.clssReportsArrange.funSetText(rpt, "eeeeeeeeee",  "The Sum in  " + CrncyName2;
text = rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["TextForignAmount"] as TextObject;
if (CrncyNo2 == "1")
Adapters.clssReportsArrange.funSetText(rpt, "eeeeeeeeee",  "#" + Amount2 + "#;
```

[image: Find and replace]

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: i tried to use this ^.*(eeeeeeeeee).*$
and it's good to select the whole line with the word 
but now i need the condition to select semicolon ; if the line contain eeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

find:

```
("eeeeeeeeee"[^\n;]*);
```

replace:

```
\1);
```

You match from `"eeeeeeeeee"` until the first `;` in line and you replace the whole match with the first capture group plus `);`

[Here a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oaHdXk/1)

EDIT: With Visual Studio 2008 you should find this:

```
{"eeeeeeeeee"[^\n;]*};
```

Further explanation:

- `"eeeeeeeeee"` matches literally `"eeeeeeeeee"`
- `[^\n;]` matches all the characters that are neither a newline (`\n`) nor a semicolon
- `*` operator stands for "zero or more"
- `{...}` is a capturing group. In the replacement you can reference its content using `\1` (where `1` is the number of the capturing group).

So, starting from `"eeeeeeeeee"`, you are matching all the non-semicolon characters in the line, until the first ";". In the replacement, you backreference all the pattern but `;`, and you concatenate it with `);`.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.90).aspx) you can find the complete regex syntax for VS08.

Comment: That's pretty close
but i just need to change ; to );
like change
Adapters.clssReportsArrange.funSetText(rpt, "eeeeeeeeee",  "The Sum in  " + CrncyName2;
to
Adapters.clssReportsArrange.funSetText(rpt, "eeeeeeeeee",  "The Sum in  " + CrncyName2);

Comment: @masalahi This is exactly what the regex does (see the demo).

Comment: only in demo but in actual visual studio 2008 its change it to

Adapters.clssReportsArrange.funSetText(rpt, );

Comment: @masalahi See the edit. VS08 has different syntax for capture groups.

Comment: This is exactly right
if you have a time, Can you explain the pattern?

Comment: @masalahi Edited again ;-)